# index specific column normalization

Tags: python, pandas

I have time series data with 200+ columns.  I am currently normalizing each column to be within `[0,1]` range with `df.apply(lambda x: (x-x.min())/(x.max()-x.min()))`.  However this is not enough.  I also want to have each column to be normalized within its own range (e.g. column 1: `[0,1]`, column 2: `[1,2]`, column 3: `[2,3]`, etc.).  How can I do this?  Is there a way for the lambda function to get the index of the column it was called on (I didn't find anything like this in the docs)?

Comment: If you're using Python 3, it wouldn't be hard to replace with the lambda with an `def`-defined function using `nonlocal` to access a variable inside the parent function that can be incremented each time it is called.

Comment: that's a possibility.  Thanks.  I wish, though, there were a more idiomatic way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this?

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: (x-x.min())/(x.max()-x.min()))
for ix, col in enumerate(df.columns.values):
    df[col] = df[col]+ix
```

Another route which isn't incredibly pretty but is equally functional:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: (x-x.min())/(x.max()-x.min()))
df += pd.DataFrame([range(len(df.columns.values))]*len(df.index),columns=df.columns.values)
```

Comment: I guess if there is no idiomatic way of doing what I need, this will work.

Comment: Added a second method in.  It still isn't a one-liner, but I thought it was worth thinking about the problem from a different perspective.